# The 'Password' column does not belong to the Table. C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, ajax

I am using for my website C#, ASP.NET WebService, AJAX, JavaScript, jQuery for my website, everything was ok but now I have a problem. Problem is trying to show user profile information for this I'm using a MySQL query in my Database Class, here is it:

```
SELECT tbl_usuarios.Id, tbl_usuarios.nombreUsuario, tbl_usuarios.Contraseña, tbl_usuarios.Correo, tbl_usuarios.Nombre, tbl_usuarios.Puntos, tbl_membresia.Membresia
FROM tbl_membresia INNER JOIN tbl_usuarios ON tbl_membresia.Id = tbl_usuarios.Membresia WHERE nombreUsuario = 'paco14'
```

Works fine but however here is the tables structure:

[image: Table Structure]

There is a relationship between tbl_membresia.Id and tbl_usuarios.Membresia

Now, this is my web method:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    //Here is where I call the MySQL Query
    dt = conn.ConsultarTabla("perfil", us);

    CrearCuenta cc;
    List<CrearCuenta> lista = new List<CrearCuenta>();
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        cc = new CrearCuenta();
        cc.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["Id"]);
        cc.Usuario = dt.Rows[i]["nombreUsuario"].ToString();
        cc.Contraseña = dt.Rows[i]["Contraseña"].ToString();
        cc.Correo = dt.Rows[i]["Correo"].ToString();
        cc.Nombre = dt.Rows[i]["Nombre"].ToString();
        cc.Membresia = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["Membresia"]);
        cc.Puntos = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["Puntos"]);
        lista.Add(cc);
        cc = null;
```

And my AJAX success function:

```
success: function (data) {
        //Conversion de los datos obtenidos a un arreglo de JSON
        var aRC = JSON.parse(data.d);
        //Variable lineas que permitira dibujar la tabla HTML
        var lineas = "";
        //FOR para recorrer el arreglo
        for (var i = 0; i < aRC.length; i++) {
            //Variables que guardaran el dato obtenido en el arreglo
            var id = aRC[i].Id;
            var num = id;
            var user = aRC[i].Usuario;
            var pass = aRC[i].Contraseña;
            var correo = aRC[i].Correo;
            var nombre = aRC[i].Nombre;
            var memb = aRC[i].Membresia;
            var puntos = aRC[i].Puntos;


            $('#user').val(user);
            $('#pass').val(pass);
            $('#correo').val(correo);
            $('#nombre').val(nombre);
            $('#membresia').val(memb);
            $('#puntos').val(puntos);



        }
    }
```

What I'm doing wrong? And how can I solve it?

Comment: You do know that storing password in plain text is bad, right? You shouldn't be able to show users their password, because the passwords should be irreversibly hashed.

Comment: I know bro, but is a project requirement.

Comment: Totally agree with the error: "The 'Password' column does not belong to the Table"

Comment: That's the kind of requirement you refuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the problem is with the 'ñ' char, try using Contrasena or Password instead of Contraseña.